# Calling bean function on h:link tag in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hyperlink, navigation

I am using jsf 2.0 with prime faces 5.5. i have an

```
 <h:link onClick="#{searchBean.resetLists}" ....
```

pl tell me if this or any other set up could be used here. my compulsion is h:link, i cant change it to commandLink or commandButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a remote command

`<p:remoteCommand name="resetLists" action="#{searchBean.resetLists}"/>`

`<h:link onclick="resetLists()" ....`

You can read more about remoteCommand in the [PrimeFaces ShowCase.](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml)